# Download files in Razor Pages by AJAX method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, download, razor-pages

I have a form with large no:of fields to input data.
The Page also has file upload option like below
[image]

Want to download the files without submitting this form and also without refreshing this page. what have done so far is

```
@if (Model.AttachForms != null)
            {
            <div class="form-row mt-1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.AttachForms)
                            {
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pt-1 pb-1">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" value="@item.Name" id="FileDownloadBtn">Download</button>
                        </li>
                            }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
```

Javascript Code

```
$("#FileDownloadBtn").click(function () {
       event.preventDefault();
        
        var rootPath = '@Url.Content("~")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: rootPath + "/RequestFormEdit?handler=FileDownload",
            data: { filename: this.value },
            success: function (data) {

            }
        })
    })
```

cshtml.cs

```
public IActionResult OnPostFileDownload(string filename)
        {
            //string DownloadFileName = filename;
            if (filename != null)
            {
                var Folder = RequestID.ToString();
                string fileview = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents", Folder, filename);
                WebClient User = new WebClient();
                Byte[] fileBuffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileview);
                if (fileBuffer != null)
                {
                    return File(fileBuffer, "application/octet-stream", filename);
                }
            }
            return null;
            
        }
```

My doubt is how can to pass this file content data as json string and download the file as same as the uploaded format.

---

### Edited

Edited the filedownload button with formdata, but still its not working.
My doubt is i am passing file name in the download button like below

```
<ul class="list-group">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.AttachForms)
                            {
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pt-1 pb-1">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)                            
                            <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" value="@item.Name" id="FileDownloadBtn">Download</button>
                        </li>
                            }
                    </ul>
```

Do i need to give get().files in jquery?

```
$("#FileDownloadBtn").click(function () {
       event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData();
        var rootPath = '@Url.Content("~")';
        var files = $("#FileDownloadBtn").get(0).files;
        formData.append('Files', files[0]);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: rootPath + "/RequestFormEdit?handler=FileDownload",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        })
    })
```

This is my backend code to download

```
public IActionResult FileDownload(string filename)
        {
            //string DownloadFileName = filename;
            if (filename != null)
            {
                var Folder = RequestFormMaster.RequestID.ToString();
                var fileUploadPath = _fileuploadurl;
                string fileview = Path.Combine(fileUploadPath, Folder, filename);
                WebClient User = new WebClient();
                Byte[] fileBuffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileview);
               
                if (fileBuffer != null)
                {
                    return File(fileBuffer, "application/octet-stream", filename);
                }
            }
            return null;
            
        }
```

---

### FILE UPLOAD

```
<div class="col-sm-4 mb-2 pl-sm-2" >
            <label class="pl-4 pt-2"><b>Upload Attachments</b></label>

            <div class="form-row" style="border:3px dashed #D3D3D3;outline-offset:-10px;height:75px;border-radius:5px;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="attachment" style="padding: 15px 145px;">
                        <a class="btn" style="background-color:#E9ECEF;" role="button" aria-disabled="false">Click here to upload files</a>
                    </label>
                    <input id="attachment" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; display: block;" type="file" asp-for="ReqSupportingFiles" multiple>
                </div>
            </div>
            @if (Model.AttachForms != null)
            {
            <div class="form-row mt-1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.AttachForms)
                            {
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pt-1 pb-1">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)                            
                            <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" value="@item.Name" id="FileDownloadBtn">Download</button>
                        </li>
                            }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
            <div class="form-row mt-1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p id="files-area">
                        <span id="filesList">
                            <span id="files-names"></span>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You need to get file content in `$("#FileDownloadBtn").click`,and use [FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675778/asp-net-core-3-1-upload-file-with-listobject-via-ajax-call-send-it-to-cont) to pass file data.

Comment: hi @Yiyi You , i have edited my code by following the suggested link. But its not working, do i need to give get(0).files ,since i am passing file name in button click.

Comment: What is the content of `$("#FileDownloadBtn").get(0).files`?

Comment: @YiyiYou, i am listing the filename in a button,where i am passing the file name. #FileDownloadBtn is not a input file.When i click on this button i should be able to download the file.

Comment: You need to pass file content to handler,so there is useless to pass `$("#FileDownloadBtn").get(0).files`.

Comment: @YiyiYou how can i pass the file content to handler, as i am passing only file name in the button.

Comment: Can you share more about your html?What is `Click here to upload files` in your html?

Comment: @YiyiYou, Edited my code above i am saving the file to network drive folder, and listing the file from network drive as a list item,just displaying their names.I dont want to refresh the page and submit the form as well upon clciking the download button.Thats why opted for AJAX.

Comment: Is `$("#attachment").get(0).files` the files you want?

Comment: @YiyiYou $attachment is actually for uploading the file.I dont want to upload the file,what i needed is only download the file which im already uploaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241482/discussion-between-teena-and-yiyi-you).

Comment: `$attachment is actually for uploading the file.`Your files are stored in `$("#attachment").get(0).files` rather than the `<li></li>`.